# Load and using js file on node command line

Tags: javascript, node.js

How I load a js file to using it on node command line?

I tried

```
> var myfile = require('./myfile.js');
> myfile.doSomething();
```

> result: myfile.doSomething is not a function

But *myfile* var is empty (no function, no var);

Answer (score 0):

The command expression only works when I put:

> Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

in myfile.js and using exports (without above expression, export wont worked).

```
// myfile.js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

exports.doSomething = function() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

So, after this changes, my command lines works:

```
> var myfile = require('./myfile.js');
> myfile.doSomething();
```

> result: hello